# ArgumentError when calling directly a query with cequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cassandra, cequel

I've just updated cequel from 1.10.0 to 3.2.1 and I'm having the following model:

```
module Messaging
  class ThreadsForUser
    include Cequel::Record
    include Sunspot::Cequel

    self.table_name = :messaging_threads_for_users

    key :user_id, :bigint
    key :thread_id, :timeuuid, order: :desc
```

and I have the following query (this was working correctly with 1.1.0):

```
  connection.execute(
    "DELETE FROM #{table_name} WHERE thread_id = ? AND user_id in (?)",
    thread_id, user_ids
  )
```

but with 3.2.1 I'm receiving:

```
ArgumentError: argument for "user_id" must be bigint, [3] given
```

where `user_ids` is an array with a 3 on it. Not sure how can I fix this, any idea?

Comment: What if you remove the parenthesis around the second placeholder question mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use syntax as here:

```
DELETE FROM #{table_name} WHERE thread_id = ? AND user_id in ?
```

In this case the full list will be substituted by driver into `in`, while in your variant, you're passing the `IN` consisting of one element - it's valid syntax, you simply need to pass integer value instead of list of integers.